# RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression text should startwith

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, textbox

I have write on aspx.cs side this code. I want to validate the textbox with this rule, text should start with XYZ. But it doesn't work. When i try "XYZjhsdfk", validator returns the error message of the RegularExpressionValidator. But it should pass, because "XYZjhsdfk" starts with "XYZ".

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^" + "XYZ";
```

I have tried many things and searched on google but i can not make it work like i want.

I have also tried these:

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^" + "XYZ" + ".";
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^" + "XYZ" + "*";
```

Comment: It should be `@"^XYZ.*"`.

Comment: Try `.*` in the place of `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex used in `RegularExpressionValidator` should match the whole string.

You may add `.*` after `^XYZ` to match that part:

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^XYZ.*";
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `XYZ` - some literal value
- `.*` - one or more chars other than a newline (replace with `[\s\S]*` to match any chars, but this would be only good if the input could contain newlines, which is probably not the case here).

Comment: Thats it. Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew !